# How to combine multiple aggregate query in a mongodb

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I want to find an easy way to combine 3 ratings together for a mongoDB query. Specifically, is there some way to combine 3 aggregate calls in one. So for example i have the below data. Which lists ratings for movies, either in imbd.rating, tomato.rating or metacritic, I'd like to find the top 2 movies for each of these ratings. The bottom query is how i'm fetching the top 2 results based on the tomato.rating

data

```
 {
        "title": "Once Upon a Time in the West",
        "year": 1968,
        "rated": "PG-13",
        "runtime": 175,
        "countries": [
            "Italy",
            "USA",
            "Spain"
        ],
        "genres": [
            "Western"
        ],
        "director": "Sergio Leone",
        "writers": [
            "Sergio Donati",
            "Sergio Leone",
            "Dario Argento",
            "Bernardo Bertolucci",
            "Sergio Leone"
        ],
        "actors": [
            "Claudia Cardinale",
            "Henry Fonda",
            "Jason Robards",
            "Charles Bronson"
        ],
        "plot": "Epic story of a mysterious stranger with a harmonica who joins forces with a notorious desperado to protect a beautiful widow from a ruthless assassin working for the railroad.",
        "poster": "http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTEyODQzNDkzNjVeQTJeQWpwZ15BbWU4MDgyODk1NDEx._V1_SX300.jpg",
        "imdb": {
            "id": "tt0064116",
            "rating": 8.6,
            "votes": 201283
        },
        "tomato": {
            "meter": 98,
            "image": "certified",
            "rating": 9,
            "reviews": 54,
            "fresh": 53,
            "consensus": "A landmark Sergio Leone spaghetti western masterpiece featuring a classic Morricone score.",
            "userMeter": 95,
            "userRating": 4.3,
            "userReviews": 64006
        },
        "metacritic": 80,
        "awards": {
            "wins": 4,
            "nominations": 5,
            "text": "4 wins \u0026 5 nominations."
        },
        "type": "movie"
    },
    {
        "title": "A Million Ways to Die in the West",
        "year": 2014,
        "rated": "R",
        "runtime": 116,
        "countries": [
            "USA"
        ],
        "genres": [
            "Comedy",
            "Western"
        ],
        "director": "Seth MacFarlane",
        "writers": [
            "Seth MacFarlane",
            "Alec Sulkin",
            "Wellesley Wild"
        ],
        "actors": [
            "Seth MacFarlane",
            "Charlize Theron",
            "Amanda Seyfried",
            "Liam Neeson"
        ],
        "plot": "As a cowardly farmer begins to fall for the mysterious new woman in town, he must put his new-found courage to the test when her husband, a notorious gun-slinger, announces his arrival.",
        "poster": "http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTQ0NDcyNjg0MV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwMzk4NTA4MTE@._V1_SX300.jpg",
        "imdb": {
            "id": "tt2557490",
            "rating": 6.1,
            "votes": 126592
        },
        "tomato": {
            "meter": 33,
            "image": "rotten",
            "rating": 4.9,
            "reviews": 188,
            "fresh": 62,
            "consensus": "While it offers a few laughs and boasts a talented cast, Seth MacFarlane's overlong, aimless A Million Ways to Die in the West is a disappointingly scattershot affair.",
            "userMeter": 40,
            "userRating": 3,
            "userReviews": 62945
        },
        "metacritic": 44,
        "awards": {
            "wins": 0,
            "nominations": 6,
            "text": "6 nominations."
        },
        "type": "movie"
    },
    {
        "title": "Wild Wild West",
        "year": 1999,
        "rated": "PG-13",
        "runtime": 106,
        "countries": [
            "USA"
        ],
        "genres": [
            "Action",
            "Western",
            "Comedy"
        ],
        "director": "Barry Sonnenfeld",
        "writers": [
            "Jim Thomas",
            "John Thomas",
            "S.S. Wilson",
            "Brent Maddock",
            "Jeffrey Price",
            "Peter S. Seaman"
        ],
        "actors": [
            "Will Smith",
            "Kevin Kline",
            "Kenneth Branagh",
            "Salma Hayek"
        ],
        "plot": "The two best hired guns in the West must save President Grant from the clutches of a nineteenth-century inventor-villain.",
        "poster": "http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BNDI5NDk5MjgxMl5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwNjI1MTUyMQ@@._V1_SX300.jpg",
        "imdb": {
            "id": "tt0120891",
            "rating": 4.8,
            "votes": 124558
        },
        "tomato": {
            "meter": 17,
            "image": "rotten",
            "rating": 4.1,
            "reviews": 130,
            "fresh": 22,
            "consensus": "Bombastic, manic, and largely laugh-free, Wild Wild West is a bizarre misfire in which greater care was lavished upon the special effects than on the script.",
            "userMeter": 28,
            "userRating": 2.7,
            "userReviews": 463740
        },
        "metacritic": 38,
        "awards": {
            "wins": 10,
            "nominations": 11,
            "text": "10 wins \u0026 11 nominations."
        },
        "type": "movie"
    },
    {
        "title": "West Side Story",
        "year": 1961,
        "rated": "UNRATED",
        "runtime": 152,
        "countries": [
            "USA"
        ],
        "genres": [
            "Crime",
            "Drama",
            "Musical"
        ],
        "director": "Jerome Robbins, Robert Wise",
        "writers": [
            "Ernest Lehman",
            "Arthur Laurents",
            "Jerome Robbins"
        ],
        "actors": [
            "Natalie Wood",
            "Richard Beymer",
            "Russ Tamblyn",
            "Rita Moreno"
        ],
        "plot": "Two youngsters from rival New York City gangs fall in love, but tensions between their respective friends build toward tragedy.",
        "poster": "http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTM0NDAxOTI5MF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwNjI4Mjg3NA@@._V1_SX300.jpg",
        "imdb": {
            "id": "tt0055614",
            "rating": 7.6,
            "votes": 67824
        },
        "awards": {
            "wins": 18,
            "nominations": 11,
            "text": "Won 10 Oscars. Another 18 wins \u0026 11 nominations."
        },
        "type": "movie"
    },
    {
        "title": "Slow West",
        "year": 2015,
        "rated": "R",
        "runtime": 84,
        "countries": [
            "UK",
            "New Zealand"
        ],
        "genres": [
            "Action",
            "Thriller",
            "Western"
        ],
        "director": "John Maclean",
        "writers": [
            "John Maclean"
        ],
        "actors": [
            "Kodi Smit-McPhee",
            "Michael Fassbender",
            "Ben Mendelsohn",
            "Aorere Paki"
        ],
        "plot": "A young Scottish man travels across America in pursuit of the woman he loves, attracting the attention of an outlaw who is willing to serve as a guide.",
        "poster": "http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BNTYxNDA5ODk5NF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwNzMwMzIwNTE@._V1_SX300.jpg",
        "imdb": {
            "id": "tt3205376",
            "rating": 7,
            "votes": 19101
        },
        "tomato": {
            "meter": 92,
            "image": "certified",
            "rating": 7.5,
            "reviews": 115,
            "fresh": 106,
            "consensus": "Slow West serves as an impressive calling card for first-time writer-director John M. Maclean -- and offers an inventive treat for fans of the Western.",
            "userMeter": 75,
            "userRating": 3.7,
            "userReviews": 9850
        },
        "metacritic": 72,
        "awards": {
            "wins": 2,
            "nominations": 9,
            "text": "2 wins \u0026 9 nominations."
        },
        "type": "movie"
    },
    {
        "title": "An American Tail: Fievel Goes West",
        "year": 1991,
        "rated": "G",
        "runtime": 75,
        "countries": [
            "USA"
        ],
        "genres": [
            "Animation",
            "Adventure",
            "Family"
        ],
        "director": "Phil Nibbelink, Simon Wells",
        "writers": [
            "Flint Dille",
            "Charles Swenson",
            "David Kirschner"
        ],
        "actors": [
            "Phillip Glasser",
            "James Stewart",
            "Erica Yohn",
            "Cathy Cavadini"
        ],
        "plot": "A family of Emigre mice decide to move out to the west, unaware that they are falling into a trap perpetrated by a smooth talking cat.",
        "poster": "http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTYzODMxNTUyNF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwMTAwMzQyMQ@@._V1_SX300.jpg",
        "imdb": {
            "id": "tt0101329",
            "rating": 6.4,
            "votes": 16013
        },
        "awards": {
            "wins": 0,
            "nominations": 0,
            "text": ""
        },
        "type": "movie"
    },
```

tomato.rating get

```
   db.MovieData.aggregate([
          { "$unwind": "$tomato" },
          { "$sort": { "tomato.meter": -1 } },
          { "$limit": 2 },
          {"$project": {title:1, "tomato.meter":1}},
        ])
```

imbd

```
db.MovieData.aggregate([
  { "$sort": { "imdb.rating": -1 } },
  { "$limit": 2 },
  {"$project": {title:1, "imdb.rating":1}},
])
```

Meta critic

```
db.MovieData.aggregate([
  { "$sort": { "metacritic": -1 } },
  { "$limit": 2 },
  {"$project": {title:1, "metacritic":1}},
])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These sort of *"limitted"* operations are perfectly suited to [`$facet`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/):

```
db.MovieData.aggregate([
  { "$facet": {
    "tomato": [
      { "$sort": { "tomato.meter": -1 } },
      { "$limit": 2 },
      {"$project": {title:1, "tomato.meter":1}},
    ],
    "imdb": [
      { "$sort": { "imdb.rating": -1 } },
      { "$limit": 2 },
      {"$project": {title:1, "imdb.rating":1}},
    ],
    "metacrtic": [
      { "$sort": { "metacritic": -1 } },
      { "$limit": 2 },
      {"$project": {title:1, "metacritic":1}},
    ]
  }}
])
```

Returns from the data in the question:

```
{
        "tomato" : [
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("5c80979542dd84d91e5547d9"),
                        "title" : "Once Upon a Time in the West",
                        "tomato" : {
                                "meter" : 98
                        }
                },
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("5c80979542dd84d91e5547dd"),
                        "title" : "Slow West",
                        "tomato" : {
                                "meter" : 92
                        }
                }
        ],
        "imdb" : [
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("5c80979542dd84d91e5547d9"),
                        "title" : "Once Upon a Time in the West",
                        "imdb" : {
                                "rating" : 8.6
                        }
                },
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("5c80979542dd84d91e5547dc"),
                        "title" : "West Side Story",
                        "imdb" : {
                                "rating" : 7.6
                        }
                }
        ],
        "metacrtic" : [
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("5c80979542dd84d91e5547d9"),
                        "title" : "Once Upon a Time in the West",
                        "metacritic" : 80
                },
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("5c80979542dd84d91e5547dd"),
                        "title" : "Slow West",
                        "metacritic" : 72
                }
        ]
}
```

As long as the [results are *"small"*](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/#BSON-Document-Size) then it's perfectly okay to run multiple pipelines this way.

If results are *large* it would be better to run independent queries and preferably in parallel ( i.e under `Promise.all()` for NodeJS for example ) and combine results ( as the `Promise.all()` example would ).

Whilst this effectively requires more database connections, that additional overhead is typically negated by the parallel processing. And of course means combined results ( especially when processed from cursors ) would not cause the [BSON limit](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/#BSON-Document-Size) on a response to be broken.

> **NOTE**: `tomato` is an `Object` and not an `Array`, so you don't use `$unwind`

Comment: If the results are large, say over 2000 would you recommend another way?

Comment: Also interestingly, if i put the limit above 2- i only get a NumberInt(9) back in the IMBD object, and that's all i get back in the metacritic object.

Comment: @chris Additional explanation added as well as my output from the data in your question.